# How to install nfslock daemon

Tags: nfs, lock, nfsv4

I want to learn the NFS locking mechanism I surfed on net. Using `nfslockd` or `rpc.lockd` we can do. But in Debian there is no package. Anyone please help me whether shall we do or not in Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older versions of NFS (v2/v3) could be used without locks.  To support locks a separate locking daemon was used on the server alongside nfsd.

With NFSv4 (which you have the question tagged), locking is a required part of the protocol and a separate lock daemon is not used for v4 services.

If you have an nfsv4 mount, you should be able to lock a file within similar to how you lock a file on your local filesystem.

> Thanks for your comments I want to lock file in server itself, if one client use a file, another client don't access until first client release. I want to avoid this type race condition.

Unix uses advisory locking, enforced at the client, not the filesystem (which is how Windows tends to do it).  This means that all your clients need to participate in locking.

If your clients request a lock before accessing the file, then all will be well.  Only after other clients release the lock with the other client gain the lock.  `fcntl` calls are usually supported on both local and NFS filesystems.

Take a look at [File Locking in UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Unix-like_systems) on Wikipedia for some background.

Comment: Thanks for your comments I want to lock file in server itself, if one client use a file, another client don't access until first client release. I want to avoid this type race condition.

Answer (score 0):

NFS lock is part of the NFS process. You don't install it. Also, this doesn't work as you are thinking. If you use this a MUTEX lock will not be passed to all servers. The only software i have ever seen do this well is VERITAS.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you specifically for debian, but this is my `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` file from SLES 11.4 (which is using NFS v3 I think).

```
#    # Path:        Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:     number of threads for kernel nfs server
#    # Type:        integer
#    # Default:     4
#    # ServiceRestart:  nfsserver
#
# the kernel nfs-server supports multiple server threads
#
USE_KERNEL_NFSD_NUMBER="4"

#    # Path:        Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:     use fixed port number for mountd
#    # Type:        integer
#    # Default:     ""
#    # ServiceRestart:  nfsserver
#
#  Only set this if you want to start mountd on a fixed
#  port instead of the port assigned by rpc. Only for use
#  to export nfs-filesystems through firewalls.
#
MOUNTD_PORT=" xxx  "   set to port opened in firewall!

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         GSS security for NFS
#    # Type:                yesno
#    # Default:             yes
#    # ServiceRestart:      nfs nfsserver
#
# Enable RPCSEC_GSS security for NFS (yes/no)
#
NFS_SECURITY_GSS="no"

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         NFSv4 protocol support
#    # Type:                yesno
#    # Default:             yes
#    # ServiceRestart:      nfs nfsserver
#
# Enable NFSv4 support (yes/no)
#
NFS4_SUPPORT="no"

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         NFSv4 server minor version
#    # Type:                integer
#    # Default:             0
#    # ServiceRestart:      nfsserver
#
# Select NFSv4 minor version for server to support (0, 1).
# If '1' is selected, both NFSv4.0 and NFSv4.1 will be supported.
NFS4_SERVER_MINOR_VERSION="0"

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Network Status Monitor options
#    # Type:                string
#    # Default:             ""
#
# If a fixed port should be used to send reboot notification
# messages to other systems, that port should be given
# here as "-p portnumber".
#
SM_NOTIFY_OPTIONS="-p xxxxx"    set to port opened in firewall

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Always start NFS services
#    # Type:                yesno
#    # Default:             no
#    # ServiceRestart       nfs
#
# Always start NFS services (gssd, idmapd), not only if
# there are nfs mounts in /etc/fstab.  This is likely to be
# needed if you use an automounter for NFS.
#
NFS_START_SERVICES=""

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Port rpc.statd should listen on
#    # Type:                integer
#    # Default:             ""
#    # ServiceRestart:      nfsserver
#
# Statd will normally choose a random port to listen on and
# SuSE-Firewall is able to detect which port and allow for it.
# If you have another firewall, you may want to set a fixed
# port number which can then be opened in that firewall.
#
STATD_PORT="xxxxx"     set to port opened in firewall

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Hostname used by rpc.statd
#    # Type:                string
#    # Default:             ""
#    # ServiceRestart:      nfsserver
#
# statd will normally use the system hostname in status
# monitoring conversations with other hosts.  If a different
# host name should be used, as can be useful with fail-over
# configurations, that name should be given here.
#
STATD_HOSTNAME=""

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:     TCP Port that lockd should listen on
#    # Type:                integer
#    # Default:             ""
#    # ServiceRestart:      nfsserver
#
# Lockd will normally choose a random port to listen on and
# SuSE-Firewall is able to detect which port and allow for it.
# If you have another firewall, you may want to set a fixed
# port number which can then be opened in that firewall.
# lockd opens a UDP and a TCP port.  This setting only affect
# the TCP port.
#
LOCKD_TCPPORT="xxxxx"    set to port opened in firewall

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:     UDP Port that lockd should listen on
#    # Type:                integer
#    # Default:             ""
#    # ServiceRestart:      nfsserver
#
# Lockd will normally choose a random port to listen on and
# SuSE-Firewall is able to detect which port and allow for it.
# If you have another firewall, you may want to set a fixed
# port number which can then be opened in that firewall.
# lockd opens a UDP and a TCP port.  This setting only affect
# the UDP port.
#
LOCKD_UDPPORT="xxxxx"   set to port opened in firewall

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Lease time for NFSv4 leases
#    # Type:                integer
#    # Default:             ""
#
# Set the lease time for the NFSv4 server.  This allows new locks
# to be taken sooner after a server restart, so it is useful for
# servers which need to recover quickly after a failure, particularly
# in fail-over configurations.  Reducing the lease time can be a
# problem is some clients connect over high latency networks.
# The default is 90 seconds.  A number like 15 might be appropriate
# in a fail-over configuration with all clients on well connected
# low latency links.
NFSV4LEASETIME=""

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Alternate mount point for rpc_pipefs filesystem
#    # Type:                string
#    # Default:             ""
#
# In a high-availabilty configuration it is possible that /var/lib/nfs
# is redirected so some shared storage and so it is not convenient to
# mount the rpc_pipefs filesystem at /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs.  In that
# case an alternate mount point can be given here.
RPC_PIPEFS_DIR=""

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Options for svcgssd
#    # Type:                string
#    # Default:             ""
#
# Normally svcgssd does not require any option.  However in a
# high-availabilty configuration it can be useful to pass "-n"
# to guide the choice of default credential.  To allow for that
# case or any other requiring options ot svcgssd, they can
# be specified here.
SVCGSSD_OPTIONS=""

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Extra options for nfsd
#    # Type:                string
#    # Default:             ""
#
# This setting allows extra options to be specified for NFSD, such as
# -H <shared_hostname> in a high-availability configuration.
NFSD_OPTIONS=""

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Extra options for gssd
#    # Type:                string
#    # Default:             ""
#
# Normally gssd does not require any options.  In some circumstances,
# -n, -l or other options might be useful. See "man 8 rpc.gssd" for
# details.  Those options can be set here.
GSSD_OPTIONS=""

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Extra options for mountd
#    # Type:                string
#    # Default:             ""
#
# Normally mountd does not require any options.  In some circumstances,
# -n, -t, -g or other options might be useful. See "man 8 rpc.mountd" for
# details.  Those options can be set here.
# -p or -N should be set using MOUNTD_PORT or NFS4_SUPPORT rather than
# this option.
MOUNTD_OPTIONS=""

#    # Path:                Network/File systems/NFS server
#    # Description:         Avoid DNS lookups for kerberos principal
#    # Type:                yesno
#    # Default:             no
#    # ServiceRestart:      gssd
#
# Avoid DNS lookups when determining kerberos identity
# of NFS server (yes/no)
# "yes" is safest, but "no" might be needed to preserve
# correct behaviour at sites that don't use
# Fully Qualified Domain Names when mounting NFS Shares.
#
NFS_GSSD_AVOID_DNS="no"
```

the "nfs lock daemon" should be somewhat inherent to the nfs package installed, and should just work.  A dependency to NFS is RPC with `rpc.mountd` and `rpc.statd` and `rpc.lockd`.  So with NFS properly installed (along with it's required dependencies such as RPC and Portmap) it should work provided you either turn the firewall off, or configure to specify static ports for `lockd` and `mountd`.  If you don't specify a static port then NFS will choose these **randomly** every time it starts [during boot].  With a firewall [typically on by default] you'll never be able to account for these randomly chosen port numbers and that will prevent the *locking* mechanism from working every time.

note, my info here is NOT for NFSv4.